# Get Channel Id discord with request (python)

Tags: python, python-requests, request, discord

```
def send_dm():
     token = 'i know, just not putting my token here'
     message = 'yo, dont mind just testing smth'
     id = "681089525702721546"
     header = {
         'authorization' : token,
         'user-agent' : 'i know, just not putting my user_agent here',}
     payload = {'content' : message}
sd = requests.post(f"https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/{id}/messages", headers=header, data=payload)
print(sd.status_code)
```

So i am trying too send for fun too my friend a message with python requests but i just find out that you need to get the channel id for the direct message, but i dont know how, can someone help me finding out?

Answer (score 0):

Per documentation [Create DM](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/user#create-dm) with a user (`recipient_id`) to return a [Channel Object](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#channel-object).
In this returned object the `id` key will be the id of this channel that you can use to send a message in the way you tried to.

If you want to send a message to a spesific/public channel you can get a list of all the channels via [Get Guild Channels](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#get-guild-channels)

Comment: even for sending a message with requests its like that?

Comment: @BAD3VA You can also copy the channel id in the client as in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Discord Settings
2. Click on Advanced under App Settings

[image: SS of setting]

3. Toggle Developer Mode

[image: Dev Mode SS]

4. Go to the channel of your choice
5. Right-click and click on `Copy-ID`

[image: ID SS]